# Installation instructions to import psycopg2 using PyCharm CE for Mac?

Tags: python, postgresql, pycharm, psycopg2

There are many posts detailing errors in psycopg2 installation and import when using PyCharm. Like many others, I believe I had installed Postgres (used pgAdmin 4) and psycopg2 (previous answers suggested using pip and homebrew) but could not get the latter to load through PyCharm. Although this seems to be a relatively common issue that has been discussed, I have yet to find straightforward instructions--not just retroactive troubleshooting--that pick up after installation of PyCharm and Postgres. I've seen some posts with screenshots that seem like they might be relevant but they look like a different version of PyCharm than mine (Community 2.2). What are the basic steps that should allow one to import psycopg2 when using PyCharm on a Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by changing 
from:
   include-system-site-packages = false
to
   include-system-site-packages = true

in the file pyvenv.cfg from the folder venv

Hope it helps...